# Android: Modifying Object's Fields With Its Own Click Listener

Tags: java, android, listener, android-radiobutton

I have several radio buttons, each of which has a `View.OnClickListener`. The whole purpose of those listeners are for me to be able to change the color of the text associated with the `RadioButton` upon clicking this very `RadioButton`. My problem is, I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is how I set a listener for each `RadioButton`:

```
radioButton.setOnClickListener(badAnswerListener());
```

Here's the `badAnswerListener` method:

```
private View.OnClickListener badAnswerListener(){
     return new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             //How do I change the radioButton's color?

         }
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If radioButton is private member of class :

radioButton.setTextColor(R.color.customcolor);

See this too, it's almost the same question :

[Changing Text color of RadioButton if clicked in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436219/changing-text-color-of-radiobutton-if-clicked-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

if you are only using radio button clicklistners to change the color of text.Have a look at the better approach.To change the text color when radio button is checked(clicked)

1) Use radio_text_selector.xml as below and put it into res/color folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/red" />
   <item android:color="#504f4f" /> <--default case
</selector>
```

Use the above selector in "android:textColor" attribute like below

```
<RadioButton 
     android:id="@+id/radioButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
     android:textColor="@color/radio_text_selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private View.OnClickListener badAnswerListener(){
     return new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             // Change the clicked radioButton's text to red
             ((RadioButton) arg0).setTextColor(Color.RED);
         }
     };
}
```